# How can this set expression be simplified?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can i simplify this expression $(((x \cup  y) -(x \cap y )) \cup z ) - (((x \cup  y) -(x \cap y )) \cap z )$ ?

Mainly, I'm trying to find a way to simplify $(((x \cup  y) -(x \cap y )) \cup z )$ since the other term is just an intersection instead of an union.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say it is the symmetric difference of $z$ with the symmetric difference of $x$ and $y$.

Or objects that are elements of exactly one of the following sets: $x,y,z$
It is also $x\cup y\cup z-x\cap y-x\cap z- y\cap z$

Comment: Hmm, by definition its the symmetric difference, but i'm trying to simplify it to show that the symmetric difference is associative.

Comment: Doesn't the second sentence show it is associative?

Comment: Not immediately, since the second sentence is $( x \cup ((y \cup  z) -(y \cap z ))) - ( x \cap ((y \cup  z) -(y \cap z )))$

Comment: But you can denest $x\cap(y\cup z)$ and then show it is associative

Comment: But doesn't $ ((y \cup  z) -(y \cap z )) $ have higher precedence in the expression?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets try working with those identities, I'm at your disposition, need you anything else.

Comment: thanks for your attention and time @Bananarama, the problem was solved when $(A-B)$ was replaced by $A \cap B^{c}$

Comment: If this answer helped you you can accept it or even upvote it, otherwise I would like to know if I can help you more.